# Python Selenium trying to export a file

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I stumbled upon Selenium yesterday and was able to successfully log into a website and navigate to a page that I normally have to do manually. I tried to copy the xpath but the element cannot be found. It looks like this:

[image]
I want to navigate to the Data --> CSV Format and click on it.

I edited this to include the top of the inspect element. This goes down to the Export to PDF option, just keep in mind I want the CSV Format, not PDF.

```
<document>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" style="visibility: visible;">
<head>
<body class="PortalBody HTMLBody" style="">
<div class="HeaderContainer">
<script type="text/javascript">obips.history.create();</script>
<form style="position: absolute; top: -1000px; display:none;">
<script>var dashboardCurrentStyle = "FusionFx" </script>
<div id="idEmbedFrameDiv" style="" src="saw.dll?ReloadDashboard&InFrameset=false&Page=Dashboard%20Insight&Embed=true&PortalPath=%2fshared%20-%20DW%2f_portal%%20Dashboard%20Detail&Caller=Dashboard&ViewState=01qglnht7bjvn3nf9qrofvafjm"/>
<script type="text/javascript">obips.ResourceManager.seedResource({p:"common/privileges.xml",v:{exprs:{"canAccessCatalogUI":true,"canAccessCatalogSearchUI":false,"canAccessHomePage":true,"canAccessSimpleSearchField":false,"canAccessAdvancedSearchLink":false,"canAccessOpenMenu":true,"canAccessNewMenu":true,"canAccessHelpMenu":true,"canAccessDashboardsMenu":true,"canAccessFavoritesMenu":true,"canAccessMyAccountLink":true,"canAccessCustomLinks":false,"enableClientStorage":true,"enableSessionStorage":true,"enableLocalStorage":true,"canReloadMetadata":false,"canOpenMetadataDict":false}}});saw.header.alertsNode = ""; saw.header.renderHeader(null, 'Dashboard Detail', '', '', {'Oracle': 'olh/l_en/toc.htm', 'Oracle Publisher': "saw.dll?xmlpObjectTasks" + '&Action=help', 'Marketing': 'olh/l_en/marketing/mstoc.html' });saw.getSessionInfos().portalPath='/shared/_portal/Dashboard Detail';</script>
<script type="text/javascript">obidash.pageIdentifier = 'sfcjp24m8jpf8gbu';obidash.canSaveSelectionForMe = true;</script>
<div id="idPersonalizationMenu" class="NQWMenu" sdir="right" menuinit="" href="javascript:void(null)" onmouseout="NQWMenuMouseOut(event)" onmouseover="NQWMenuMouseOver(event)">
<div id="idDashboardPrintDisplayLayoutMenu" class="NQWMenu" sdir="left" submenuinit="" href="javascript:void(null)" onmouseout="NQWMenuMouseOut(event)" onmouseover="NQWMenuMouseOver(event)">
<div id="idDashboardPrintManageLayoutMenu" class="NQWMenu" sdir="left" submenuinit="" href="javascript:void(null)" onmouseout="NQWMenuMouseOut(event)" onmouseover="NQWMenuMouseOver(event)">
<div id="idDashboardExportToExcelMenu" class="NQWMenu" sdir="left" submenuinit="" href="javascript:void(null)" onmouseout="NQWMenuMouseOut(event)" onmouseover="NQWMenuMouseOver(event)">
<div id="idSavedSelectionsMenu" class="NQWMenu" sdir="left" submenuinit="PersonalizationEditor.getSavedSelectionsMenu" href="javascript:void(null)" onmouseout="NQWMenuMouseOut(event)" onmouseover="NQWMenuMouseOver(event)">
<script src="res/b_mozilla/common/componentheader.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<span id="sawruler" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"/>
<div class="ComponentHeader ">
<iframe id="idEmbed" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px;" src="res/empty.htm" name="idEmbed" title="idEmbed"/>
<div id="idDownloadLinksMenud:dashboard~p:sfcjp24m8jpf8gbu~r:tom49amoppk60jjc" class="NQWMenu" onmouseover="NQWMenuMouseOver(event)" style="visibility: visible; display: block; position: absolute; top: 422px; left: 820px;" binit="true" role="menu" aria-activedescendant="popupMenuItem">
<table class="menuShadowWrapper" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="shadowMenuCell" colspan="2" rowspan="2">
<a id="popupMenuItem" class="NQWMenuItem NQWMenuItemWIconMixin" onclick="NQWClearActiveMenu();Download('saw.dll?Go&ViewID=d%3adashboard%7ep%3asfcjp24m8jpf8gbu%7er%3atom49amoppk60jjc&Action=Download&SearchID=c7gl7pgfjfdkhekcg09p3p8guq&Style=FusionFx&PortalPath=%2fshared%20-%20DW%2f_portal%20Dashboard%20Detail&Page=Dashboard%20Insight&ViewState=5cb5o5dpdpsh5id2japa3i0rvu&ItemName=Report%20Data&path=%2fshared%20-%20DW%20Dashboard%20New%20Report%20Data&Format=pdf&Attach=1'); return false" href="javascript:void(null);" name="SectionElements" style="width: 119px;" tabindex="0" role="menuitem" aria-label="PDF">
<table class="MenuItemTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="MenuItemIconCell">
<td class="MenuItemTextCell">PDF</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</a>
```

Comment: Well, if you can show the full HTML code or URL then it would be better. But if you really can't, there's only one `a` tag in your HTML code part, do you want just click that?

Comment: Looks like you'd need to use the `ActionChain()` class and its associated methods. It will allow you to do the mouse-over type actions you'd likely need to do.

Comment: I tried to add a bit more information, hopefully it helps. I am totally new to this stuff unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML for "Export" menu header and "Data" menu item is not given. Hence making assumptions for them.

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id="menu"]//td[text()="Export"]')
menuItem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id="menu"]//td[text()="Data"]')
subMenuItem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id="MenuItemTable"]//td[text()="CSV Format"]')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(menu)
actions.move_to_element(menuItem)
actions.move_to_element(subMenuItem)
actions.click(subMenuItem)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: I can try this. The xpath for the Export button works. I can see it pop up correctly. I just wasn't able to navigate from there.

Comment: ".//*[@id='popupMenuItem']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]" This is the xpath that is given for all of the menu items. So I am not able to specify 'Data' or 'CSV Format'. This is the xpath for the Export button which does work though: ".//*[@id='d:dashboard~p:sfcjp24m8jpf8gbu~r:tom49amoppk60jjcLinks']/tbody/tr/td[5]/a"

Comment: `.//*[@id='popupMenuItem']/table/tbody/tr/td[text()='Data']`  can be tried.

Answer (score -1):

```
Actions a =new Actions(driver);
a.moveToElement(xpath of Export).moveToElement(xpath of Data).moveToElement(xpath of CSV Format).click().perform();
```

Comment: This is a business intelligence portal that runs through oracle. It also requires a username and password etc. I was hoping the 'Inspect Element' portion would be enough.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Yeah but StackOverflow says 'You must have 50 reputation to comment' .So @kevin guan ask StackOverflow about this

Comment: Actions a =new Actions(driver);
a.moveToElement(xpath of Export).moveToElement(xpath of Data).moveToElement(xpath of CSV Format).click().perform();

Comment: @KetanSethi: Then you should post some *real answers* to get these 50 rep. Its' very easy, since I got 100 rep today.

Comment: @kevinguan Ok sir sure

Comment: Wait, I don't think this is Python code. OP is *running selenium using Python*.